# Use of the word Canonical

Tags: scala, functional-programming

This might be a bit ambiguous but I'm struggling to get a tangible explanation of the use of the word canonical when reading about Scala and FP in general.

Some statements I have read:

- *`Vector` is the canonical concrete type for `Seq`*
- *What is the canonical way to do this in Scala?*

My understanding of the *canonical form* (in computing) is that it represents -
 *The default unique representation where more than one possible representation is possible*.

1. Is it acceptable to say that asking *what is the canonical way of doing something*, is really just the same as asking *what is the idiomatic way of doing something*?
2. Is there a way to discover what the canonical type is for any abstract type in the Scala hierarchy in a particular context?

Comment: I think this might fit Programmers or CS better than SO, but do check their help section first.

Comment: As far as I understand, it is just the english word `canonical` with the normal meaning. Nothing special to Scala.

Comment: What's a `Seq`?

Comment: *just the english word canonical with the normal meaning* - normal as in which context??? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SarveshKumarSingh points out, generally in Scala, the word canonical means the same as it does elsewhere in English. So yes as to point 1, you can use canonical like that.

Point 2 is more interesting because the Scala standard library strongly suggests that certain concrete collections are the canonical implementations of abstract traits by having the `apply` method on the companion object return a specific concrete class that is just upcast to the abstract type.

To tell which concrete class is actually created when you do say `Seq(1, 2, 3)`, if you have a little bit of familiarity with the collections hierarchy, you can just take a look at the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala). In this case you'll see the `Builder` for a `Seq` is a `ListBuffer`, which means `Seq.apply` will give you back a `List` (not a `Vector`, you get that from `IndexedSeq`).